# Rubyのレシーバーの値を取得する方法

Tags: ruby

```
def aaa
 puts レシーバー + 50
end

100.aaa
```

これの結果の150を表示させる方法はどうすればよいのでしょうか？
引数ではなくレシーバー（100）の値をメソッド内に取得する方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Integer
  def aaa
    puts self + 50
  end
end
```

aaa methodをどこに定義しなければならないか？を考えると良いと思います。
当然レシーバーとなる100のclassに定義してあげないと、100にはmethodが増えません。
`100.class`などの結果から100という数字がなんのclass objectなのかも調べると良いと思いますよ。

`特異method`とか`オープンクラス`とかのキーワードでぐぐってみると色々情報が見つかりますよ。
ただし、使い方には注意してくださいね。特に既存methodのoverrideなどは慎重に...

ruby 2.4.1

Comment: ありがとうございます！オープンクラスでやりたい事が上手くいきました！